# How does the html of menu control get the image from a web resource url when I set the default dynamic pop out image true?

Tags: asp.net, .net

when I put in a menu control on a page, and set the default dynamic pop out image true, the resulting html to the client gets the image from a web resource url under my project folder.  How does that work?  Where is the actual image, and how does the web resource get generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, this will help you 
   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910442